# Session.send() does not work: "session is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, web-development-server

I am trying to use `session.send` instead of `console.log` in `transporter.sendMail`, so that the user knows when the Email was sent successfully, but it does not work.
The error is "session is not defined".
This is how my code looks like:

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Create the transporter with the required configuration for Gmail
// change the user and pass !
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
        user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'myPassword'
    }
});

// setup e-mail data
var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Our Code World " <myemail@gmail.com>', // sender address (who sends)
    to: 'mymail@mail.com, mymail2@mail.com', // list of receivers (who receives)
    subject: 'Hello', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world </b><br> This is the first email sent with Nodemailer in Node.js' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info,session){
    if(error){

        return console.log(error);
    }

    session.send('Message sent: ' + info.response);
}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an example of how to doing it. Just make sure you call this method inside a session context like:

```js
const sendmail = require('./email'); // in case you have the class called email

bot.dialog('/', function(session) {


sendmail.sendmail(session);


session.send("hello")

});
```

```js
function sendmail(session){

  var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

  // Create the transporter with the required configuration for Outlook
  // change the user and pass !
  var transport = nodemailer.createTransport( {
      service: "hotmail",
      auth: {
          user: "",
          pass: ""
      }
  });

  // setup e-mail data, even with unicode symbols
  var mailOptions = {
      from: '"Our Code World " <shindar902009@hotmail.com>', // sender address (who sends)
      to: 'shindar902009@hotmail.com', // list of receivers (who receives)
      subject: 'Hello ', // Subject line
      text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
      html: '<b>Hello world </b><br> This is the first email sent with Nodemailer in Node.js' // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
      if(error){
          return console.log(error);
      }

      session.send('Message sent');

  });


}
module.exports.sendmail = sendmail;
```

Answer (score 1):

`transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info , session)`

You are not using a correct function definition, since the callback of transport.SendMail can only have two parameters (error & info). Have a look at the [Nodemailer example](https://nodemailer.com/about/#example).

In your case it would look like this. Just make sure you use this snippet where the `session` context is available.

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return session.error(error);
    }

    session.send('Message sent: ' + info.messageId);
});
```

Comment: I wrote this snippet in a separated nodejs file where there is no session context. How can i define it please?

Comment: You should include `session` in the function you call, from where you have session context. It is hard to advise without seeing more code..

Comment: you mean if i had the nodemailer in function sendemail(from , to ) should i include the session parameter in the function so that it looks like : function  sendemail(from , to , session) and call it where i defined session ?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this snippet replacing the username and password appropriately and ended up with this:

```html
{ Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continu> Please log in via
534-5.7.14 your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/ - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\projects\nodemailertest\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:605:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\projects\nodemailertest\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1340:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (C:\projects\nodemailertest\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:378:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\projects\nodemailertest\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:764:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\projects\nodemailertest\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:570:14)
    at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (C:\projects\nodemailertest\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:522:47)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?..._sniped> Please log in via\n534-5.7.14 your web browser and then try again.\n534-5.7.14  Learn more at\n534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 534,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
```

Furthermore I received an email from Google:

```html
Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your account from a non-Google app. Google blocked them, but you should check what happened. Review your account activity to make sure no one else has access.
```

Are you sure this is the code that you're running? The error you posted, "session is not defined" seems like a syntax error.

Comment: @Mohid Ali i am using this code and its working perfectly fine. But i want to send "message sent" to the bot so that the user knows when the email was sent successfully